# A few questions about installing Ubuntu prior to Windows on 2 separate SSDs

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

My planned formatting/partitioning scheme is as follows:

*(I know this is probably not the recommended way, but under the circumstances, and due to lack of disk space, it seems like the only way.
)*

**120GB Kingston SSD** ( securely erased by use of `hdparm`)
**TBW: 64TB** ( according to the manufacturer's [documentation](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sv300s3_us.pdf) )

1. An 30GB /-partition for UbuntuStudio 16.04.
   I'm considering EXT4 along with the option to disable journaling...
   Good idea?
2. A 3GB /swap-partition (8GB RAM available - no hibernation intended; I am, however, interested in exploring the possibilities of the video-editing software included in Ubuntu Studio).
   Swapiness set to 0 or 1: Could someone clarify whether there would be a noticeable difference between those two values?
   [Mohammadh](https://superuser.com/questions/1090435/a-few-questions-about-installing-ubuntu-prior-to-windows-on-2-separate-ssds/1090476#1090476) tells me I won't need to care about choosing a filesystem for the /swap partition.
3. <strike>An NTFS /home partition...</strike> I update that: Make it a /data partition of nearly 90GB - also recognized by Windows 7 that I'm planning to install on another ssd. What filesystem would you recommend?
4. A /boot partition, if needed... Yes, I think I'll give it a try... How small could it be? And again, what filesystem would you recommend?

---

5. So far, am I talking primary partitions? Or should I be thinking in terms of extended and logical partitions? If so, why? (As for Mohammadh's sugestion to check whether I'm using UEFI or legacy BIOS, I believe my Gigabyte H55M-UD2H motherboard does *not* support UEFI.)

---

6. Are there any pros & cons for doing all this via the Ubuntu installer itself vs GParted vs the gnome-disks utility?

---

**480GB Kingston SSD:

TBW: 256TB**

Backup as much as possible, wipe it, and then install Windows 7 Ultimate upon it.

---

7. All in all, does this sound like a plausible sequence of steps?

Comment: To hell with it... I did some partitioning in GParted, creating a 512MB partition at the very beginning of my SSD, followed by a 32GB extended partition, wherein I created a 3GB swap area and a 29GB EXT4 partition, leaving the remaining 87-something GB unformatted for now. Then I ran the installer, making an EXT4 /boot partition out of the 512MB, a and a /root one out of the 29GB. The question about the optimal fs for a /data partition recognized by both Ubuntu and Win7 still remains, as does the one about swapiness set to 0 as compared to 1...

Answer (score 0):

1. 30GB for Ubuntu is fair. But if you plan to install large-size software, pay some more attention.
2. If you don't need hibernate, you can set any size you want for the swap partition. If your RAM is enough, the swap would not be used. It doesn't need any filesystem.
3. NTFS partition should not be used as `/home`. If you need to access your home directory from Windows, consider installing some third party application to support the ext filesystem in Windows. (Check [3 Ways to Access Your Linux Partitions From Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).)
4. You don't need a separate `/boot` partition. It is optional.

By the way, some other things:

- You should first install Windows and then Linux. Grub boot loader finds Windows OS, but Windows doesn't find Linux.
- Check whether you are using UEFI with GPT partitions, or legacy BIOS with primary-logical partitions.
- I suggest that you first install Windows, then make the partition table with GParted, and then install Ubuntu.

Comment: My UbuntuStudio live USB is currently the only working OS I've got, so installing Windows first isn't really an option, as no installation cd:s or other removable media are available. I've got to install Ubuntu, then do some backup, and then reformat my USB stick to a bootable Windows USB, so I can install Win on my other ssd. And from what I've read I can update the grub boot loader afterwards to tackle Windows' inability to find Linux, right? Btw, any guidance as to check the UEFI vs legacy BIOS issue would be appreciated.

Comment: @m.a.a. ok you can install ubuntu first. but after installing windows, you should update grub as you said. to check UEFI or legacy BIOS, you can check the system bios. but if you are not sure, just install ubuntu and windows. if ubuntu failed to boot, boot on live ubuntu and use "boot-repair" as the ubuntu help page recommends.